# rebaking my tezos from kukia wallet

Tags: baking, kukai

I want to rebake my tezos which are currently baked at kukai.

May you help me how to start the rebaking process please?

BR

**EDIT:** "reBaking" is a term used by a scammers trying to impersonate the TF or other community teams to steal users' data and ultimately funds. If you receive an email or other kind of DM promoting such service, please report to scamreport@tezos.com

Comment: "rebake" is a not a term used on the Tezos blockchain. Can you please explain with more details as to what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: You seem to confuse "baking" (running a validator) and "delegating" (choosing a delegate to vote and produce blocks on your behalf, and usually compensate you).

Comment: thank you quick responing. As mentioned above, it seemed to be a scam. I've already reported it! Watch out if you receiving tezos mails fro <noreply@ecuabet.com>

Comment: @Haksimilain please mark the answer below as top answer to close the question out, thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a scam, rebaking is a scam! Please do not do this! For more information check the Tezos Foundation website with known scams: https://tezos.foundation/security/known-scams/